# How to implement a firebase cloud functions in ionic?

Tags: typescript, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I want to implement a function with firebase functions, but the problem is that in the firebase panel it is never reflected that something is being done.

this is my functions code, the idea is get all data from a specific document with specific id.

```js
exports.identifyusers=functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    
    var db = admin.firestore();
    const key=req.query.key;
    
   return db.collection("usuariosdinny").doc(key).get().then(snapshot => {
   
    console.log("Correcto")

    }).catch(reason => {
        res.send(reason)
    })
});
```

this is the part when i invoke the function:(this part is a auth process that is correct the user i get the id and going to send this id to the function)

```js
this.afAuth.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(userst.email,userst.password)
        .then(res=> 
          {
            
          console.log(this.afAuth.auth.currentUser.uid);
          var tipo= firebase.functions().httpsCallable('identifyusers').arguments(this.afAuth.auth.currentUser.uid);
          console.log(tipo);

          if(tipo=="Cliente Dinny")
          {
            console.log("Es un cliente");
          }
          else{
            console.log("No tiene permiso para")
          }         
          }
        
          
          //this.navCtrl.push(TabsControllerPage)&& loader.dismiss())
        ).catch(reject =>alert.present() && loader.dismiss());
      }).catch(reject=>loader.dismiss());
```

thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your client code is attempting to call a "callable" function:

```
firebase.functions().httpsCallable('identifyusers')
```

But your function is defined as an HTTP type function:

```
exports.identifyusers=functions.https.onRequest(...)
```

If you want to invoke a callable function, you will have to write a callable function.  [Read the documentation for callable functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable) to understand how to do that.

```
exports.identifyusers = functions.https.onCall(...)
```

Comment: when i implement the function with this option, i can't deploy

Comment: Sounds like you now have a different problem to ask a new question about.